# how to push the data to client browsers in php

Tags: php, mysql, push

How can i  push the data from Server to Client browser using php and JavaScript.

If  i change any thing from server side admin page the client side (Browser need to update)

Ex:

I have to admin panel and user pages . If i update anything from admin side all the user need to get this update by means of push.

Note:

Not a Ajax request like getting the data request in certain time duration OR refresh the browser in a certain time duration .

**I need to push this to client pages. How can i do this ?**

Comment: What has it to do with apple or mysql?

Comment: use `websocket`,`longpolling` or `node.js`.

Comment: see this once hopes usefull for u http://stackoverflow.com/a/8647329/2550071

Comment: Redesign your approach and accept that the client only see the changes on a refresh. Either that or do it with Ajax or websocket

Answer (score -3):

all you have to do is to SELECT!

$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$result = mysqli_query($query) or die ('failed');